# Error in percentage calculation

Tags: c#, double, percentage

Trying to calculate percentage amount but it always return a 0.

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                double igst_amt;

```
            double amt = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[4].Index].Value)) * (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[5].Index].Value));
            row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[6].Index].Value = Convert.ToString(amt);
            igst_amt = (igst/100)*(amt);
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(igst_amt));
            if (state == "o")
            {
                row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[9].Index].Value =Convert.ToString( (cgst / 100) *( amt));
                row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[11].Index].Value =Convert.ToString( (sgst / 100) * (amt));
            }
            else if (state == "i")
            {
                row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[7].Index].Value = igst_amt;
            }
            double g_total = igst_amt + amt;
            row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[13].Index].Value = Convert.ToString(g_total);
            double t_g_total=0;
            t_g_total+= g_total;
        }
```

Comment: What is the type of `igst`?

Comment: data type is double
double igst=0;
 double cgst=0;
  double sgst=0;

Comment: Does `igst` become non-zero?

Comment: yes its getting  expected value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down to the basic code required to reproduce the issue:

```
int igst = 10;
double amt = 42;
double igst_amt = (igst / 100) * (amt);

Console.WriteLine(igst_amt);
```

With this I get a result of `0`.

However, if I write it like this:

```
double igst = 10;
double amt = 42;
double igst_amt = (igst / 100) * (amt);

Console.WriteLine(igst_amt);
```

Then I get `4.2`.

I suspect that `igst` is actually an integer and you're performing integer arithmetic which will result in `0`.

You should change `igst` to `double` or you can do this:

```
int igst = 10;
double amt = 42;
double igst_amt = igst * amt / 100;

Console.WriteLine(igst_amt);
```

A simple change to the calculation and it works.

Also, as a side note, you appear to be doing monetary calculations using `double`, but you should be using `decimal` as it is designed for money calculations.